# Factory pattern with different protocols in swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift4.2

I am trying to use factory pattern in swift, and give is my code

I have two protocols

```
protocol MyProtocol1{
    func callLoginAPI()
}

protocol MyProtocol2{
    func callPaymentAPI()
}
```

I have two structures which conform to these protocols

```
struct MyManager1: MyProtocol1{
    func callLoginAPI()
    {
        debugPrint("Inisde--MyManager1 and ready to call an Login API")
    }
}

struct MyManager2: MyProtocol2{
    func callPaymentAPI()
    {
        debugPrint("Inisde--MyManager2 and ready to call Payment API")
    }
}
```

I want to use the factory pattern to create the instance of Manager by passing the Protocol and returning a concrete object of the struct that conforms to that protocol

**Example:** `ManagerFactory.create(MyProtocol1) --> should give me instance of MyManager1 and doing ManagerFactory.create(MyProtocol2) --> should give me instance of MyManager2`

I assume that this may not work as I am asking for a concrete type at runtime, so I ended up doing something like this

```
protocol IManagerFactory{
    func getMyManager1() -> MyProtocol1
    func getMyManager2() -> MyProtocol2
}

struct ManagerFactory: IManagerFactory
{
    func getMyManager1() -> MyProtocol1 {
        return MyManager1()
    }

    func getMyManager2() -> MyProtocol2 {
        return MyManager2()
    }
}
```

But I am curious if what I am trying to do in the example is achievable, I am using swift 4.2.

I have seen other examples but all of them have the same protocol which they conform to like rectangle, square and circle conform to same protocol shape.

In my case, I have two separate protocols which do completely different things so is that even possible what I am trying to do in the example? OR the way I ended up with is the only way to go about it.

Please suggest what is the best possible approach.

Comment: It can only work if the two protocols share a common ancestor and the factory method would need to have a return type of the ancestor. You would then need to downcast to the expected actual protocol

Comment: @Paulw11thanks for the response, I already tried that approach and it works, but in this situation, the protocols don't refer a common ancestor and hence that approach becomes void, do you think the approach I came up with is the only way to go or it could be improvised?

Comment: You could have a function that returns `Any` and use a downcast, but that would be worse than what you have. I don't really understand why you are using a factory pattern at all.

Comment: well I was just playing around with swift and coming from C# background in c# doing this would have been easy but i assume swift does things in a different way so I think i will go with what I have done so far coz retuning Any would definitely be worse. My idea was to use a creator pattern to create objects for me, having one method to rule them all than having multiple functions @Paulw11

Comment: I could see the C# in your `IManagerFactory` naming.  Swift is strongly typed and tries as hard as possible to avoid runtime issues with incompatible types by doing a lot of work at compile time.

Comment: hahaha you got me there :) well then I guess I would stick to the grounds of what swift wants me to do @Paulw11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm very suspicious of a "manager" that is a value (a struct) rather than an instance (a class). Do you really mean to be using structs and protocols here at all? Structs have no identity; two structs with the same properties must be completely interchangeable for each other, and things like that don't usually get named "manager."

What you're describing is certainly writeable. It's just kind of useless. Here's how you write it:

```
struct ManagerFactory {
    static func create(_ type: MyProtocol1.Protocol) -> MyProtocol1 {
        return MyManager1()
    }

    static func create(_ type: MyProtocol2.Protocol) -> MyProtocol2 {
        return MyManager2()
    }
}

let mgr1 = ManagerFactory.create(MyProtocol1.self)
let mgr2 = ManagerFactory.create(MyProtocol2.self)
```

But this is just an elaborate way to use method overloading to replace names.

What you seem to want is a single method, but what would its return type be? Even in C#, I don't think this is writable without adding nasty downcasts. (This is the point you and paulw11 discuss in the comments.) This isn't a limitation of Swift; it's a fundamental characteristic of types. Even in JavaScript, you'd need to know what you expect to get back or else you won't know what methods you can call on it (it's just you track that expectation in your head and docs rather than in the compiler and code).

You seem to have created a lot of protocols here, and I'm betting they mostly have exactly one implementation. That's bad Swift. Don't create protocols until you have a specific need for one. Don't create attractions for fun. They will burn you very quickly.

If your protocols really look like this, and you *really* have different implementations of these methods (i.e. don't do this if there is only one implementation of `MyProtocol1` "just in case"), what you really want are functions:

```
struct API {
    let login: () -> Void
    let payment: () -> Void
}

let myAPI = API(login: myLoginFunction, payment: myPaymentFunction)
```

This will let you create different APIs if you need them. But again, only if you *need* this flexibility. If not, just use classes for instances, and structs for values, and avoid protocols until you have at least 2, and better 3, implementations in your program.

Comment: I wanted all the project and payment entity to be together in their individual protocol so as to implement the single responsibility principle. I agree with the point where this should not be a struct and should be a class. I thankyou for such clean and detailed explanation.

Comment: I would say these protocols violate single responsibility. You can slice the responsibility as "abstracts the network API" or you could slice the responsibility as "handles payments (including the API and logic)," but it's hard to imagine a good use of single responsibility that represents exactly one API call, but not the logic. (i.e. is it likely that a change would impact exactly this one method and nothing else? that seems uncommon.)

Comment: The real lesson is that this kind of abstraction should not be undertaken until the system and how it changes is more fully understood, and then you should refactor to use that experience. Preemptive abstraction layers (chasing DRY or single responsibility before they've become an issue) tend to slice the problem in the wrong direction, and you wind up with complexity that doesn't later pay off. This is *particularly* an issue in Swift where it is very easy to get yourself into type corners with protocols and generics.

Comment: I used single method to showcase my issue, in real I have like 5 of those methods belonging to a single entity and hence the protocol route. I used protocols as user can pay via paypal or other services so different providers different logic and security implementations, Payment is just one example I faced in the project there are plenty others too.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest a swifty option:

```
protocol Manager {
    // a generic protocol for all managers
}

protocol BadManager: Manager {
    // properties and behaviour of BadManager
    mutating func noBonus()
}

protocol GoodManager: Manager {
    // properties and behaviour of GoodManager
    mutating func bigBonus()
}

protocol ManagerFactory {
    associatedtype Manager
    mutating func createManager() -> Manager
}

struct gm: GoodManager {
    mutating func bigBonus() {
        print("tons of cookies & coffee")
    }
}

struct bm: BadManager {
    mutating func noBonus() {
        print("all fired")
    }
}

enum ManagerCreator<Manager>: ManagerFactory {
    func createManager() -> Manager {
        switch self {
        case .goodManager:
            return gm() as! Manager
        case .badManager:
            return bm() as! Manager
        }
    }
    case goodManager
    case badManager
}
```

Comment: Ah, the force down-casting screws it up :/